# Time to be used in calculating bandwidth

Tags: cuda

I am trying to find the effective bandwidth used by my code against the CUDA GEforce 8800 gtx maximum of 86GB/s .I am not sure what time to use though .Currently I am using the difference between calling the kernel with my instructions against calling the kernel with no instructions.Is this the correct approach?(formula i use is ->effective bw= (bytes read+written)/time)

Also I get a really bad kernel call overhead (close to 1 sec) .Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: you won't get precise results from sending a few bytes back and forth. the cuda toolkit ships with a bandwith test - use that.

Comment: @Dave - the question is not about determining the bandwidth of his card, but determining the "efficiency" of his kernel when compared to the max bandwidth.

Comment: does the 1s overhead that you see happen *every* time the kernel is launched? (ie, if you launch more than one kernel in a single program run, is the overhead only on the first launch or on all of the launches?)

Comment: Sry for the late response.Yes the overhead is on all the calls..everytime I launch the kernel.Infact even an empty kernel takes some time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can time your kernel fairly precisely with cuda events.

```
//declare the events
cudaEvent_t start;
cudaEvent_t stop;
float kernel_time;

//create events before you use them
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);

//put events and kernel launches in the stream/queue
cudaEventRecord(start,0);
myKernel <<< config >>>( );
cudaEventRecord(stop,0);

//wait until the stop event is recorded
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);

//and get the elapsed time
cudaEventElapsedTime(&kernel_time,start,stop);

//cleanup
cudaEventDestroy(start);
cudaEVentDestroy(stop);
```

Comment: Yes this is similar to what I do .However  the kernel launching part takes quite long .Downsampling a total of 6 images of 2000*512 takes close to 1.39 sec(only the kernel) against 1.16 sec( calling an empty kernel).I use cudaTimers though to measure this.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what to say about your launch. How many times do you call your kernel? Is there a cudaMalloc or any other cuda call before you launch it?

Comment: I just call the kernel once in my program( to downsample).there are few cudamallocs in the program but none between the launch and return from kernel .Its something like starttimer ....kernel<<<>>> ....stoptimer.I then use cutGetTimerValue divided by 1000 to report time in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Effective Bandwidth in GBps=  **( (Br + Bw)/10^9 ) / Time**

**Br** = number of bytes read by kernel from DRAM

**Bw** = number of bytes written by kernel in DRAM

**Time** = time taken by kernel.

For example you test the effective bandwidth of copying a 2048x2048 matrix of floats (4 bytes each) from one locations to another in GPU's DRAM. The formula would be:

Bandwidth in GB/s = **( (2048x2048 x 4 x 2)/10^9 ) / time-taken-by-kernel**

here:

**2048x2048** (matrix elements)

**4** (each element has 4 bytes)

**2** (one for read and one for write)

**/10^9** to covert B into GB.

Comment: Thanks jawad.I did read this in the cuda manual .However it did not answer my point.If I take the time spent between kernel launch and returning I get ver very poor bandwidth (less than .5 gb/s) .Therefore I was wondering if I should use the difference?

Comment: So you get 0.5 GB/s on a kernel with some computational-instructions or just read/write kernel?

Comment: Your kernel may not be well optimized even with only read/write instructions. Here's a snapshot of official slide from NVIDIA (http://www.tunacode.com/Optimization.png) showing a kernel giving 2 GB/s can be optimized up to 44 GB/s for a specific case (just by changing read/write patterns and execution style). So I think you are calculating the bandwidth correctly.

Comment: Yes I get this with executing the kernel fetching 4 neighboring pixel values +division operation+storing the result.If i divide the bytes transferred by total kernel execution time(and not the difference).I would get something that is 100 times worse than current.

Comment: If you can share the kernel code, I may be able to optimize it.